# First Javascript Project

Tags: javascript

I just started on my first JavaScript project which is a small script to detect the browser window size, and if it is below 1100px then the div `quick` will not be shown.

Here is my code:

```
<Script language="Javascript">
  function toggle(id) {
    var browserwidth =  window.screen.width;
    if (browserwidth <= 1100) {
      document.getElementByID(quick).style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      document.getElementById(quick).style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
</script>
```

but I cannot figure out for the life of me my it does not work. I am fully aware that css `@media` could do what I am trying to do but it would not work for the current project I am working on.

Comment: You haven't declared the `quick` variable. Or is it supposed to be a string `"quick"`?

Comment: Also note that you have a start tag `<Script>` and an end tag `</script>`. Although HTML is not case sensitive the case of corresponding start an end tags should mach afaik (even if this is not the case it makes it easier to read ;)).

Comment: @Charlie Then it must be **quoted**.

Comment: am i doing something stupid.. http://pastebin.com/wKwx6haK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no variable called `quick`.  We assume that should be a quoted string `'quick'`:

```
if (browserwidth <= 1100) {
  document.getElementByID('quick').style.display = 'none';
} else {
  document.getElementById('quick').style.display = 'block';
}
```

For debugging JavaScript, the [Firefox extension](http://getfirebug.com/) Firebug is recommended, or Chrome & Safari's Developer Tools console. When you run the script, errors will be printed to the console and although they won't usually tell you the exact problem, they'll usually identify where the problem occurs.

#### Update

After seeing the implementation on pastebin, your code is not executing because, well, you aren't executing it.  Your function has been correctly defined but is not being triggered by any event.  Bind it to a button `onclick` or `window.onresize` to test its functionality:

```
<button onclick="toggle('quick');">Click to toggle</button>
```

I have also used the input parameter of your function `(id)` to dynamically choose the div, rather than hard-coding `'quick'`:

```
function toggle(id) {
  var browserwidth =  window.screen.width;
  if (browserwidth <= 1100) {
    // Use id here...
    document.getElementByID(id).style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
  }
}
// For completeness, additional info ported in from comments:

// Function to call toggle()
function init() {
  toggle("quick");
} 
// Attach it to the window.onload event so it fires when the page load completes
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: @Charlie then it must be quoted as a string as I've done above.  without quotes, it is assumed to be a variable which was never defined.

Comment: @Charlie You defined the function correctly but didn't execute it. See addition above.

Comment: so how could I make that run at page load? is there an on.load?

Comment: @Charlie Just add these lines: `function init() { toggle("quick"); }`, followed by `window.onload = init();`.

Comment: @Edwin: That is not correct, it should be `window.onload = init;`.

Comment: @Felix My bad. However, I have noticed on my personal projects that it is sometimes not called when I omit the parens, even on page load.

Comment: @Edwin: Well, if you add the parenthesis, it calls the function *immediately*. If you do this in the `head` of the page and you want to access DOM elements it won't work. If you call it at the end of the page it does not matter. You don't even have to use `window.onload` then (unless you want to access image data).

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined `quick` yet. If it's not a variable, enclose it within quotes.

HTML tags are not case-sensitive, but please be consistent. Use lowercase `script`. Also, the `language` attribute is ancient. Remove it.

PS. A great place to learn (JavaScript) is <del>[W3schools.com](http://w3fools.com/)</del> https://developer.mozilla.org/ ([Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide)).

Answer (score 2):

When you use document.getElementById the "quick" should be inside quotes, `document.getElementById('quick')`

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/rCG8J/) should work. It uses some JQuery, but it's not required. the $(function (){}); is just a faster way to make it load after the DOM (webpage itself) has loaded.

Comment: Thing is, you create that function, that takes a parameter, but never actually call said function / use the id parameter inside the function. So, besides not needing said parameter, since you harcode it into the code, you never actually call the function. I'll send you a jsfiddle in a moment.